# 3180mAh battery for iPhone 5, is it safe to install?

Tags: iphone, battery

My battery is very weak in my iPhone 5, and I want stronger battery. I can buy double the size, around 2880mAh, but I want even stronger and I found one on eBay, battery for iPhone 5 with 3180mAh. Is it safe to install battery this durable into my iPhone 5? What would be the consequences, if any at all? Would be great if I could install this kind of battery and have no problems. Thanks for any advice guys!

Comment: Never buy accessories on eBay! There are many scams on those sites.

Comment: Sure, but I bought bunch of accessories already on eBay, not battery though. Each one saved me at least double the money I would otherwise give to a service.

Comment: Battery, SSD, HDD, USB PenDrives, Power Banks and Apple Lightning Cables are products you should not buy on eBay

Comment: Uh, and I forgot SD Cards and inverters for 9Volt DC to 220V/240V/whatever in your country is used

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, everything that is not official can be dangerous. You should make sure the hardware in question is not bad quality and has positive reviews. To be more sure reviews are written from users and not "bots", it would be better to buy on sites like Amazon.com , but you will never be 100% sure. BE CAREFUL!